# How to show table row depending on user role in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create table that render data which receive from server. But in this table I have cols which not all user should to see. This is my code:

```
class TableBody extends React.Component {
  state = {
    columns: {
      id: props => (
        <td key="id">
          {props._id}
        </td>
      ),
      title: props => (
        <td key="title">
          {props.title}
        </td>
      ),
      manager: props => (
        <td key="manager">
          {props.manager}
        </td>
      )
  },
  hiddenColumns: {
    user: ['manager']
  }
}
```

In state I init my columns and add columns restrictions for user (he can not see manager column). In render I do next:

```
render() {
    const hiddenColumns = this.state.hiddenColumns[this.props.role] || [];
    const columns = Object.keys(this.state.columns).filter(key => {
      return hiddenColumns.indexOf(key) === -1
    });

    return this.props.companies.map(company => (
      <tr key={offer._id}>
        {columns.map(element => this.state.columns[element](company))}
      </tr>
    ));
  }
```

I get hidden columns for current user and filter key in columns. After this I use map to go over data which receive from server and inside map I go over for each filtered columns and send element (props).

In the future, more columns will be added to this table and make this:

```
{columns.map(element => this.state.columns[element](company))}
```

will not be effective.

Maybe I can create main template and after init remove columns which user should not to see, but I don't know how.

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this completely wrong. you should never filter data specific to user role on client side.

Ideally such data should be filtered on server side and then send to client only role specific data.

With your current approach user can simply inspect browser network tab and read all other restricted columns.

Comment: From server I receive data based on user role. But I don't now how to hide unnecessary columns on UI